# How are Inspector Controls added for the header block?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

The header block has 3 inspector controls defined:

[image]

But inside the block definition there is no `InspectorControls` tag:

https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/master/packages/block-library/src/heading/edit.js

Also in the rich text control there is no `InspectorControls` definition.

How are the inspector controls for the header block being added?

Answer (score 0):

The InspectorControls are a *slot* that exposes a way for plugin/block developers to easily add/insert content into the UI.

Its reasonable to expect that the "Heading Block" source would also contain InspectorControls,
however, given that InspectorControls use [useDisplayBlockControls](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/e2b9bb2fa71244ea07e86f64838bc36e8c6ac448/packages/block-editor/src/components/use-display-block-controls/index.js) it then becomes a little less obvious how/where they are added..

Digging a bit deeper into the Sidebar ([packages/edit-post/src/components/sidebar/settings-sidebar/index.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/3ed6809ea080de815fa7971f63b59a93386396f8/packages/edit-post/src/components/sidebar/settings-sidebar/index.js)) where the "Block" component is defined, we find that **BlockInspector** is actually used:

```
{ sidebarName === 'edit-post/block' && <BlockInspector /> }
```

Which eventually leads to [gutenberg/packages/block-editor/src/components/block-inspector/](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/3ed6809ea080de815fa7971f63b59a93386396f8/packages/block-editor/src/components/block-inspector) and the revelation that the BlockInspector *contains* an InspectorControls slot..

```
    ...
    <InspectorControls.Slot bubblesVirtually={ bubblesVirtually } />
        <div>
            <AdvancedControls
                slotName={ InspectorAdvancedControls.slotName }
                bubblesVirtually={ bubblesVirtually }
            />
        </div>
    ...
```

Ref: [packages/block-editor/src/components/block-inspector/index.js](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/3ed6809ea080de815fa7971f63b59a93386396f8/packages/block-editor/src/components/block-inspector/index.js)

The block displays the controls for the attributes it supports, eg for Heading: "typography", "color" and "advanced > custom css" are displayed.